# Type safe RPC call example from GHCJS client to Yesod/Snap/Servant

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-snap-framework, ghcjs, transpiler

I have two, related questions about RPC call to `Yesod/Snap/Servant`:

1. Say I have a function on the server, written in Haskell, compiled by GHC:

   `add x y = x+y+42`

How can:

1. I call this function from the client (the client is also written in Haskell, compiled with `GHCJS`),
2. execute the function on the server,
3. return the result to the client?

Do all this in a type-safe way?

So for example, I would like to write something like this on the client:

```
main= putStrLn $ show $ add 2 3
```

Such that the add function gets **executed** on the **server.**

What is the simplest way of doing this using `Yesod/Snap/Servant` on the server and GHCJS on the client?

2) **Similarly**, I would like to write a "function" :
`getPhaseOfMoon :: IO Phase` which runs on the server and I would like to call `getPhaseOfMoon` from the client in a type-safe way.

So that I can write this on the client:

```
main= do 
   p<-getPhaseOfMoon
   putStrLn $ show p
   return ()
```

#### Which

1. goes to the server
2. the server consults the phase of the moon
3. the server returns `Phase` to the client
4. the client displays the phase of the moon in the JavaScript Console.

## Question

How can I do this with `Yesod/Snap/Servant` (server) + GHCJS (client)?

Comment: I'm also thinking about this recently. I'm using GHCJS for client and on the server side, no framework is used yet.  The best result I can find is Haste.App for the Haste compiler.  Not sure if the idea can be transported to GHCJS because GHCJS has concurrent support. Here's the link: http://haste-lang.org/haskell14.pdf

Comment: I don't know if that's what you meant here, but as a general principle, I would warn against any solution that allows an untrusted web client to run "arbitrary code" on a server. Even with Safe Haskell; we found some nasty loopholes in that over the last year.

Comment: Thanks for the warning , indeed that is a good point. The main goal of this question is to help people get started using GHCJS on the client and demo a simple way of communicating with Haskell backend.

Comment: I was told that here is tutorial on how to do this : http://ruhaskell.org/posts/web/2015/09/01/wai-rpc.html :) I need to first learn Russian. Github example: https://github.com/astynax/wai-rpc

Comment: This seems to be useful as well: http://haskell-servant.github.io/tutorial/#tutorial - I was told.

Comment: some more related links : 1) forum discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/yesodweb/unP9SnS334o/kzzenXd8cXUJ , 2) a video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bnf7AmoQ6lc 3) good paper : http://www.andres-loeh.de/Servant/servant-wgp.pdf

Comment: This link comes very close to an answer : https://github.com/arianvp/ghcjs-servant-client and this : https://github.com/plow-technologies/ghcjs-servant-client, many thanks to friendly folks at #servant for the tips

Comment: .... and this video by one of Servant's inventors : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snOBI8PcbMQ